# Visio javascript API - Can't read/extract Shape data

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, office-js, office-addins

I am unable to retrieve basic Shape information, the most important one being .getBounds(). With this i can know the (X, Y) location as well as the shape's size.

All I am able to retrieve right now is the Shape's name and text.

I am using this javascript Visio API.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/visio?view=visio-js-1.1

Here is the code i have so far.

```
 Visio.run(this.state.session, function (context) {
        var page = context.document.getActivePage();
        var shapes = page.shapes;
        shapes.load(); // This loads the shapes.

        // need to call context.sync() in order to actually read the shapes?
        return context.sync().then(function () {
            for (var i = 0; i < shapes.items.length; i++) {
                var shape = shapes.items[i];
                myShapes.push(shape);

                // At this point i know the shape's Name. 
                // but its .getBounds() is failing.
            }
        });
```

**How can i get/invoke a visio Shape's .getBounds() method?**

The error i see ( when i try to execute shape.getBounds() ) is this:

```
RichApi.Error: The value of the result object has not been loaded yet. Before reading the value property, call "context.sync()" on the associated request context.
```

Comment: Have you tried what the message suggests?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. It was not obvious at first until i read this article.
But essentially, any method i call returns a new instance of the visio proxy. Since its a new instance i need to call load/sync again.

Here's the [article](https://buildingofficeaddins.com/loading-properties/) that actually made things clear (unlike the official documentation provided by Microsoft).

See section called, **Loading on methods versus properties.**

> The reason that this is an error is that you are retrieving the object
> anew the second time when you reference it – and so you get a brand
> new proxy object, which has no knowledge of the information you loaded
> on its twin. This, by the way, is a very common mistake when working
> with collections: to first fetch collection.getItem("key") and call
> load on it, then sync, and then re-query collection.getItem("key") –
> with the latter being a brand new copy of the original object, which
> defeats the purpose of having loaded the item to begin with!

Comment: Your description of the solution doesn't match your description of the problem. Please show the code that works so your answer will be useful to others.